# How do I change the default image name for the splash/launch image in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I tried adding a Launch image key to myappname-info.plist with the value Test and a Test.png in the Resources folder but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the name of the image. If you're trying to use a different image every time the app gets launched (like some of the built-in apps) it's not possible. If you're trying to use a different image for different versions of your app, you can use Targets.

What's the reason you want to do this?

Comment: At the moment, I'm developing a web app using PhoneGap for both iPad and iPhone. However, I've come across an issue: when the app loads on an iPad it loads both the Default-Landscape.png and the Default.png (like 2 splash screens in succession rather than one). I've tried to find out how to stop this happening but I can't find any answers(including on the PhoneGap site and on SO). So I figured that if I changed the name of the iPhone image to something else the iPad app wouldn't load it.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your plist file.

Add a new element called "Launch Image"

Then, write "Test.png"

It will then be your splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a image named Default.png for to display image as a splash

just add the Default.png in Resource folder in your application